# How to exclude VMs only from starting in Azure Start/Stop VMs during off-hours Solution

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I'm using the Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution and I need to configure it in a way that it would only start specific VMs but stop all of them.
I've seen there's a variable for excluding VMs (External_ExcludeVMNames) but when adding VM names to this variable it excludes them from both starting and stopping which is not what I want.
Is there a way to separate the usage of this variable and have perhaps two variables, one to exclude from starting and one from stopping or something else that can separate that?

Comment: You could configure Auto-Shutdown on the VMs you don't want auto-started, and only use Azure Automation for the VMs you want both started and stopped.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the configuration so whenever a new VM is being created it is automatically has the Auto-Shutdown configured? Because new VMs are being created any day and I don't have a way to keep in charge about all the new VMs.

Comment: you can take a look at my solution to this problem: https://4c74356b41.com/post5781. I'd argue its more flexible\easy to use compared to the one microsoft created. and it works with some other types of resources that can be stopped

Comment: I might actually use it! Am I supposed to edit anything in the runbook itself? Apart from creating the tags to the VMs where I'm putting my input.

Answer (score 0):

The built in Start/Stop functionality does not support this.

You could solve it as follows:

- Create a resource group "ToBeStoppedOnly"
- Create a resource group "ToBeStoppedAndStarted"
- Place your VM's in the respective groups
- Create a runbook that stops VM's. Use this runbook for both resource groups
- Create a runbook that starts VM's. Use this runbook to start VM's in ToBeStoppedAndStarted

Comment: Is there a way to do that while still keeping them in their original resource group? Maybe using tags?

Comment: Yes you can use tags. You would use Get-AzResource to get a list of the VM's, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.0.0